# react-table component onClick event for a column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am using the 'react-table' component https://react-table.js.org

I want to add on click event for one column (later I will open a modal showing info based on this event).

Comment: if you look at their docs....... click `custom props`.... it shows how you can have a click event on a table row.

Answer (score 20):

You add getTrProps to ReactTable like the example:

```
const onRowClick = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
    return {
        onClick: e => {
            console.log('A Td Element was clicked!')
            console.log('it produced this event:', e)
            console.log('It was in this column:', column)
            console.log('It was in this row:', rowInfo)
            console.log('It was in this table instance:', instance)
        }
    }
}


<ReactTable data={[]} columns={[]} getTrProps={onRowClick} />
```

Comment: For some reason, I am only getting a value back for "rowInfo" and not state, column, or instance. I cannot find out why this might be the case.  Please help?

Comment: I am having the same issue

Answer (score 5):

At the time of this writing, React-Table 6.8.0:

The value of 'column' in 'getTrProps' property is always undefined.

You'll have to use 'getTdProps' property instead.

Comment: This package is so bad. Hard to find documentation for some important features:(

Comment: The package in itself is not that bad but the documentation certainly is!