# react-table getTrProps onclick event

Tags: react-table

Please help me pass the userid from the onclick event to a new end point.
Below is my code. Console.log gives me the correct output, but both  &  tags did not seem to work in the below scenario.

```
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
                    return {
                        onClick: e => {
                            console.log(rowInfo.original.userid);
                           <a href={'/user/profile/' + `${rowInfo.original.userid}` + '/info'}/>
                        }
                    }
                }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-table component onClick event for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112105/react-table-component-onclick-event-for-a-column)