# How to get React Table Row Data Onclick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props, react-table

Hi I am trying to set up my react app such that when you click on a button in a row item in my react-table the data in that row is passed onto another component. At the moment I am simply trying to console.log the correct data but am unsure of how to pass react-table row data based on click. How can I do this?
Thanks

My Dummy data stored in state along with the button (Show Detailed View) which I want to trigger the data passing onclick:

```
    columns: [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "fname"
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "lname"
      },
      {
        Header: "Employee Group",
        accessor: "egroup"
      },
      {
        Header: "Date of Birth",
        accessor: "dob"
      },
      {
        Header: "",
        id: "id",
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <button onClick={e => this.handleShow()}>
            Detailed View
          </button>
        )
      },
    ],
    posts: [
      {
        fname: "gerald",
        lname: "nakhle",
        egroup: "faisbuk",
        dob: "8/10/1995"
      }
    ]
```

My Call to render the table:

```
<ReactTable columns={this.state.columns} data={this.state.posts}></ReactTable>
```

My onclick handler function but im not sure how I can access the table row data I'm after

```
handleShow(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add an onClick handler for the row

```js
const onRowClick = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
    return {
        onClick: e => {
            console.log('A Td Element was clicked!')
            console.log('it produced this event:', e)
            console.log('It was in this column:', column)
            console.log('It was in this row:', rowInfo)
            console.log('It was in this table instance:', instance)
        }
    }
}

<ReactTable columns={this.state.columns} data={this.state.posts} getTrProps={onRowClick}></ReactTable>
```

check this post for more info [react-table component onClick event for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112105/react-table-component-onclick-event-for-a-column)

Answer (score 8):

In your Table definition :

```
export function TableCustom({handleShow}) {
    const columns = React.useMemo(() => [{
        Header: 'Action',
        accessor: 'action',
        Cell: props => <button className="btn1" onClick={() => handleShow(props)}>Details</button>,
    },]

    return <ReactTable>;
});
```

And in your parent component : view the data of the clicked row :

```
const handleShow = (cell) => {
    console.log(cell?.row?.original);
}
```

Comment: how are you retaining the columns in the data-table component v8 ReactTable

Answer (score 5):

On @tanstack/react-table v8, you can simply put on your table component:

```
// this is your table component
<table>
   {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => {

     // onRowClick is a custom table prop -> onRowClick: (row: Row<any>) => void
     return <tr onClick={onRowClick(row)}> ... </tr>
   })}
</table>
```

And then on your component declaration:

```
<ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} onRowClick={(row) => console.log(row.original)} />
```

This is useful if you don't want to add another column to put clickable buttons, and just make the rows clickable instead.

Answer (score 2):

For React-table v7:

Pass a callback prop `onRowClicked` to the table component,

In your table component call the callback:

```
...row.getRowProps({
         onClick: e => props.onRowClicked && props.onRowClicked(row, e),
})
```

> In react-table v7, all the spread operator on HTML element that starts
> with `get...Props` are [props getter](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-give-rendering-control-to-users-with-prop-getters), for example:
>
> row.getRowProps(),  cell.getCellProps(), column.getHeaderProps(),
> getTableBodyProps(), getTableProps() etc.. You can pass any more
> attributes to extend it. for example:

```
    ...cell.getCellProps({ 
        style: {color: 'red'},  
        onClick: ()=> {}   
    })
```

Comment: this is very helpful as I was adding onClick in the td tag directly and not passing onClick as a prop to row.getRowProps function which was causing unwanted behaviour in the table.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.
`onClick={(e) => {console.log(row)}}`

Answer (score -9):

Also make sure you are binding your function in your constructor, or use the following syntax:

```
handleShow = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }
```