# React Table - radio input for useRowSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

**How can I use radio inputs instead of checkboxes for a selectable table in React Table?**

There is an example for checkboxes but not radio buttons: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/examples/row-selection/src/App.js

Changing the IndeterminateCheckox to use a radio input doesn't work as the selection state is not updated in React Table:

```
const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef();
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

    return <input name="select-radio" type="radio" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
    );
  });
```

It looks correct but does not pass the correct selection state back:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you select different options? Do you see any changes to the component / component state in your dev tools? Also, what's included in `...rest` -- does it include everything you expect? It seems most likely that your table implementation is fine and the bug is in your state implementation.

Comment: If you take a closer look at the useRowSelect example React Table stores a 'selected' state for the row which was clicked. It assumes the use of checkboxes so it allows for multiple selections to be passed down through ...rest. I think the easiest solution to this would be to implement custom radio inputs inside a data cell rather than using useRowSelect, I just thought someone else would have run into this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a quick look. Try this:

- Have a state for the rowId

```
const [selectedRowId, setSelectedRowId] = useState(null);
```

- Pass `autoResetSelectedRows: false,` to `useTable` function
- Write a click handler for the radios by hand

  `onClick={() => setSelectedRowId(row.id)}`

[image]

I have put together the working code here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-faraday-gzf7y

**Notes:**

- There might be small issues with rapidly changing value of `selectedFlatRows`. I haven't fully researched this issue but I found https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1740 . The issue says fixed but i am not completely sure.
- If you have issue with grabbing row data, try and see if the below links might be helpful
  [How to get React Table Row Data Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086420/how-to-get-react-table-row-data-onclick)
  https://codesandbox.io/s/tannerlinsleyreact-table-row-selection-hoisted-b4dvq?from-embed
  [Select row on click react-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845372/select-row-on-click-react-table)

Comment: I am trying to exclusively select only 1 row at at time, and I see that your code only does this if including `<React.StrictMode>`, can you please explain why that is?

Comment: React.StrictMode is not required. Although good to have. use toggleAllRowsSelected to set all rows as unchecked.

In the example above, add toggleAllRowsSelected to line #92 under Cell logic and then onclick do toggleAllRowsSelected(false) before updateSelectedRowId

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous answers, the solution below is with some improvements

1. Change Checkbox to Radio Input

   Inside IndeterminateCheckbox Component

   ```
   Remove  <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />*/}
   Add     <input type="radio" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
   ```
2. a) Set the initial state if you want to autoselect any row initially

   b) Deselect all the radio buttons

   c) **row.getToggleRowSelectedProps().checked** give the current state of the radio button of that row. So toggling that value accordingly. i.e

   if **checked** -> change to **unchecked** and

   if **unchecked** -> change to **checked**

   ```
   // This selectedRowIds state gives the information about which row is selected currently.
   const{state: { selectedRowIds }}=useTable(
   {
    ....
    initialState: {
         columns,
         data,
         selectedRowIds: { 2: true },  //a) I want my second row to be autoselected initially
      },
    },
    useRowSelect,
        hooks => {
            hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
                {
                    id: "selection",                    
                    Cell: ({ row, toggleAllRowsSelected, toggleRowSelected }) => {                      
                       const currentState = row.getToggleRowSelectedProps();
                       return (
                          <IndeterminateCheckbox
                             {...currentState}
                             onClick={() => {
                               // b)
                                 toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
                               // c)
                                 toggleRowSelected(row.id, !currentState.checked);
                         }} />)

                       }},
                         ...columns
                       ]);
                       })
   ```

Comment: How would you disable the select all and remove the radio button from the header row?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still struggling with this, I found different solution.

IndeterminateCheckbox is same with slight change for input type:

```
const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
    ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
        const defaultRef = React.useRef();
        const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

        React.useEffect(() => {
            resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
        }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

        return (
            <>
                {/*<input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />*/}
                <input type="radio" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
            </>
        );
    }
);
```

Then onClick we deselect all rows, and select "clicked" row. :)

```
 const {
            getTableProps,
            getTableBodyProps,
            headerGroups,
            rows,
            prepareRow,
            toggleAllRowsSelected,
            toggleRowSelected,
            state: { selectedRowIds },
        } = useTable(
            {
                columns,
                data,
            },
            useRowSelect,
            hooks => {
                hooks.visibleColumns.push(columns => [
                    // Let's make a column for selection
                    {
                        id: "selection",
                        // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
                        // to the render a checkbox
                        Cell: ({ row }) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <IndeterminateCheckbox
                                        {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
                                            toggleRowSelected(row.id, true);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    ...columns
                ]);
            }
        );
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you will be able to select multiple radio buttons.