# Add Column and Rows in React onclick

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I am new to React JS and I want to add `onClick` event to my corner cells of the table. So, `onClick` I have to add column and row adjacent to the clicked cell.

[image: Table schema]

My table initially consists of 4 column and row respectively. And on click of corner edges a column corresponding to it must be added.
For example in the image above if I click on A the column and row will be added as shown. How can I do this ?

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

var MyTable = () => {
  let [panel, setPanel] = useState([
    ["S", "O", "L", "A"],
    ["R", "P", "A", "N"],
    ["E", "L", "S", "O"],
    ["L", "A", "R", "R"],
  ]);




  function renderTable() {
    var rows = panel.map(function (item, i) {
      var entry = item.map(function (element, j) {
        return (
          <td id={j}>
            {element}
          </td>
        );
      });
      return <tr id={i}>{entry}</tr>;
    });
    return (
      <Table>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
  return <>{renderTable()}</>;
};

export default MyTable;
```

My code structure something like shown above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get React Table Row Data Onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086420/how-to-get-react-table-row-data-onclick)

Comment: I know how to get the cell value and id, but I want to know how can I add new column and row to my object panel on onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is modifying the state when onClicking a cell. When you modify your state `panel`. It will be rendered in UI as per your renderTable code.

You can modify that state `panel` by adding `onClick` event listener to your td like this -

```
return (
   <td id={j} onClick={() => handleRowColAddition(i, j)}>
      {element}
   </td>
);
```

And I am passing `i`, `j` in the function to identify the row and column of the cell.

In handleRowColAddition function, add logic to modify your state `panel`.

```
const handleRowColAddition = (i, j) => {
  // For top left cell, i is 0 and j is 0.
  if (i === 0 && j === 0) {
    
    // copying the `panel` value into temporary variable `state`.
    let state = [...panel];

    // Adding "0" at the beginning of every row. Note, "0" is for visual purposes. You can add whatever you like.
    state = state.map((row) => {
      return ["0"].concat(row);
    });

    // Making a row with 0's filled to insert at top.
    const row = Array(state[0].length).fill("0");
   
    // Appending the made row to insert at top.
    state = [row].concat(state);

    // Update the `panel` value with modified value of temporary variable `state`
    setPanel(state);
  }
};
```

I have added logic for the top left cell. If user clicks on top left cell, A column to the left and row to the top will be inserted.

Accordingly, you can add logic for other edge cells.

Here is the demo of the working solution - https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-smoke-m8liu?file=/src/Table.js